# if statement nested in for loop not working in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, grepl

```
threshold <- .3
l <-  list()

for(i in 1:length(mitochondrial_genes)) {
  if(i < length(mitochondrial_genes)) {
    for(j in (i+1) : length(mitochondrial_genes)) {
      a <- cor.test(mitochondrial_genes[,i], mitochondrial_genes[,j])
      if(grepl("*",names(mitochondrial_genes)[i])|grepl("*",names(mitochondrial_genes)[j])) {
        if(a$estimate > threshold){
          l <- c(l, list(c(names(mitochondrial_genes)[i], names(mitochondrial_genes)[j],a$estimate)))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

mitochondrial_genes is a big dataset consisting of a columns representing genes. Some of the gene names (column names) have the * symbol next to them. I essentially want to return a list of gene pairs that meet some minimum threshold value for a correlation test.

The code runs successfully, but it generates **all possible** pairs instead of just the ones that have at least one gene with a * next to its name. Basically, this part of the code seems to be the issue:

```
if(grepl("*",names(mitochondrial_genes)[i])|grepl("*",names(mitochondrial_genes)[j]))
```

Am I doing anything wrong? the if statement works in isolation when I test it out on the terminal, and the code seems to be generating all the pairs instead of filtering them based on the if statement which is confusing.

This is an example of what mitochondrial_genes looks like.

[image]

Comment: Compare `grepl("*", c("a","a*"))` with `grepl("\\*", c("a","a*"))`. `*` is regex for *"zero or more"*, but it typically needs to be preceded by something. Honestly, I assumed a lone `*` would be illegal regex syntax, but it's inferring it to mean `.*`, which translates into *"zero or more of any character"*.

Answer (score 1):

The column-selection problem is due to your regex pattern. This is strongly related to [regex to select strings which start with A, does not contain asterisk or pound sign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50144104/3358272), though in that question the `*` is both inverted (absence vs presence) and one of many rules.

In this case, there are two options:

```r
### wrong
grepl("*", c("a","a*"))
# [1] TRUE TRUE

### right
grepl("\\*", c("a","a*"))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
grepl("[*]", c("a","a*"))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Explanation:

- `*` in regex means *"zero or more"*, but more important ... *"of the preceding character/class/group"*; compare this with `+` which means *"one or more"*, also needs to be preceded by something
- typically, "anything" in regex is denoted with `.*`, where `.` means *"any character"*, and `*` still means 0 or more
- since you want the literal asterisks, you either need to escape it (`\\*` in R) or make it a class `[*]`, where inside the brackets most special characters lose their meaning (exceptions: `^`, `-`, and `]` can be included literally, but need to be done with care and restrictions)

---

There are a couple of other notes:

- you run tests for every single pair, even though you only want those where at least one of the names as an asterisk in it; inefficient, and if your data is "large-ish", then this just wasting time (and resources); better to determine which tests to do *before* running the tests
- don't use `|` or `&` in `if` statements, only `||` or `&&`; reasons:

  1. the `|`/`&` operate on logical vectors of length 0 or more, whereas `if` **requires** exactly length 1; if you use these vector variants, then you really should use `any`, `all`, or some other aggregating function "between" the condition vector and the `if`;
  2. if your conditionals are intended to be length 1, then be declarative in your programming style and use the always-length-1 `and`/`or` operators, `&&` and `||`;
  3. conditional short-circuiting: `&&`/`||` support it, `&`/`|` do not ... try this to see what this means:

     ```r
     TRUE || stop("oops")
     TRUE | stop("oops")
     ```

I fix the first bullet by using `combn` below and filtering the possible combinations. For the second, I use `|` *correctly* on vectors (not in an `if` statement), no `if` required.

Your sample data *image* (please provide something usable, [not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)) doesn't represent what you mean (there are no `*` in the names), so I'll generate some fake data and run a fake test to demonstrate the pairing mechanism.

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(a1=runif(5), b1=runif(5), "a1*"=runif(5), "b1*"=runif(5), check.names=FALSE)
dat
#      a1    b1   a1*   b1*
# 1 0.915 0.519 0.458 0.940
# 2 0.937 0.737 0.719 0.978
# 3 0.286 0.135 0.935 0.117
# 4 0.830 0.657 0.255 0.475
# 5 0.642 0.705 0.462 0.560
```

(The use of `combn` works well here because the test is symmetric: `cor.test(a, b)` is the same as `cor.test(b, a)`. If the test was directional/asymmetric, then one could use `expand.grid(names(dat), names(dat))` instead.)

Here's one way to pre-define the pairings:

```r
pairs <- as.data.frame(t(combn(names(dat), 2)))
pairs
#    V1  V2
# 1  a1  b1
# 2  a1 a1*
# 3  a1 b1*
# 4  b1 a1*
# 5  b1 b1*
# 6 a1* b1*
pairs <- pairs[grepl("[*]", pairs$V1) | grepl("[*]", pairs$V2),]
pairs
#    V1  V2
# 2  a1 a1*
# 3  a1 b1*
# 4  b1 a1*
# 5  b1 b1*
# 6 a1* b1*
```

Now we can run the tests:

```r
pairs$estimate <- mapply(function(i, j) cor.test(dat[,i], dat[,j])$estimate,
                         pairs$V1, pairs$V2)
pairs
#    V1  V2 estimate
# 2  a1 a1*   -0.611
# 3  a1 b1*    0.901
# 4  b1 a1*   -0.655
# 5  b1 b1*    0.685
# 6 a1* b1*   -0.303

threshold <- 0.3
pairs[pairs$estimate > threshold, ]
#   V1  V2 estimate
# 3 a1 b1*    0.901
# 5 b1 b1*    0.685
```